# "ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied" due converting .csv to .db

Tags: python, sqlite

**My code**

```
import csv
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

con = sqlite3.connect('D:/database.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data''')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE data(answer TEXT, reply TEXT)''')


with open('D:/database.xls.csv','rt', encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)                  
    to_db = [tuple(line) for line in reader]

cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO data (answer, reply) VALUES (?, ?)''', [to_db])
con.commit()
con.close()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\runol\source\repos\AI_ChatBot\AI_ChatBot\AI_ChatBot.py", line 19, in <module>
    cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO data (answer, reply) VALUES (?, ?)''', [to_db])
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 631248 supplied.
```

At first line 19 looked like this:
`cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO data (answer, reply) VALUES (?, ?)''', (to_db))`

Then I tried to use comma and list:
`cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO data (answer, reply) VALUES (?, ?)''', (to_db,))`
`cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO data (answer, reply) VALUES (?, ?)''', [to_db])`

Error kept the same

Answer (score 1):

`to_db` is already a list of tuples - no need to wrap it with another list. (`[to_db]`)

so the fixed line below should make it work

```
cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO data (answer, reply) VALUES (?, ?)''', to_db)
```

Comment: Then i'm getting this: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\runol\source\repos\AI_ChatBot\AI_ChatBot\AI_ChatBot.py", line 19, in <module>
    cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO data (answer, reply) VALUES (?, ?)''', to_db)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.

Comment: @AdamCupOfTea what does your csv look like? Can you provide a [mcve]